# Where are Datalab iPython notebook files stored on AppEngine?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

Where on Google cloud are Datalab iPython notebook files stored? I'd like to be able to access that directory so I can set up a git repository on GitHub if at all possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the [deprecated Cloud Datalab Deployer](https://datalab.cloud.google.com/), you can find your committed Datalab iPython notebooks at the following location in the cloud:

```
https://source.developers.google.com/p/[PROJECT_ID]/
```

If you are running [Datalab locally](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local), the notebooks will be in your `$HOME` directory on Linux/OSX or `C:/Users/<username>/Documents/` on windows.

In terms of the actual Datalab docker container, you can also find your notebooks in the `/content/` folder inside the container.

You may find the following links helpful in migrating from Cloud Source Repositories to GitHub:

- Google Cloud Datalab : [Migrating from Cloud Datalab Deployer](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/migrating)
- Cloud Source Repositories : [Adding a Repository as a Remote](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/adding-repositories-as-remotes)

Please let me know if I haven't answered your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Migrated to Contained Engine yesterday, all is well